# Macbook Pro (Early 2011) to 2560x1440 monitor?

Tags: macbook-pro, thunderbolt-display

I'm wondering whether I can connect my MBP to a 2560x1440 monitor and whether anyone else has has any success in doing so.

Answer (score 1):

Maximum supported res for external monitor is 2560x1600 so I'd say if you used a Thunderbolt/miniDisplay Port -> Display Port it ought to work. I wouldn't be so certain of DVI or indeed HDMI.